# How to use asan-win32-release-311003.zip for chrome vulnerability test?

Tags: google-chrome

Recently I saw the page 'https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447906' and want to reproduce the vul on Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1) with Chrome Version: asan-win32-release-311003 which can be downloaded on http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-asan/index.html?prefix=win32-release/.

How to run chrome with asan-win32-release-311003.zip to reproduce the vul and get logs from address sanitizer?

Answer (score 0):

```
run cmd
cd asan-win32-release-311003
chrome --no-sandbox --js-flags="--expose-gc"
```

pictures as follows:

[image: run in cmd]
[image: chrome-asan-win32 crash]